# wso2 - High availability with Postgres as database

Tags: postgresql, wso2, cluster-computing, high-availability, failover

In the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+the+Database) regarding Cluster/High availability of WSO2's databases, the example is using MySQL.
Is there any information or anyone using Postgres?
How is High Availability enforced? 
Using pgpool-II, for example?

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Setting+up+PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

You need additional tool to enforce high availability (failover, failback, switchover) in Postgres - you know that. Here is very good illustrated article by Google on how they do it using Patroni or pg_auto_failover or disk replication and Linux tools: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/architectures-high-availability-postgresql-clusters-compute-engine

Here is a list of available HA tools - especially repmgr worth your attention: https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/09/28/high-availability-for-enterprise-grade-postgresql-environments/

And here is explained how they do HA in Azure: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2019/05/30/introducing-pg-auto-failover/